# Store Cell Value but Exclude Empty Cells:

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing a code that searches Column B for changes in names then inserts a row and formulas based on variable data in columns E:J when the name changes to someone new (new value in cell). Some names are listed more than once, but consecutively, in Column B and I'd like to group it together for one total per person but it's currently doing one total each time there is ANY data in Column B, not just each time the name changes. The other issue I'm having is it is not totaling the last person because there is nothing but empty cells in Column B after the last name so nothing will ever change to activate the "THEN". I appreciate any feedback on my code. Here is what I currently have:

```
Dim firstrow As Integer
'  Start on row 7 to avoid including header
row = 7
firstrow = 1
previous = Range("B7").value
While row < 1000
'      Move to next row
    row = row + 1
    current = Range("B" & row).value
    If current <> "" And current <> previous Then
    Rows(row).Insert shift:=xlDown
'          Formulas for Columns G, I, J, and K
        Range("G" & row).Formula = "=SUM(E" & firstrow + 2 & ":G" & row - 1 & ")"
        Range("I" & row).Formula = "=sum(H" & firstrow + 2 & ":I" & row - 1 & ")"
        Range("J" & row).Formula = WS.Range("G" & row) - WS.Range("I" & row)
        Range("K" & row).Formula = WS.Range("J" & row) / WS.Range("G" & row)

        row = row
        firstrow = row
    End If
    previous = current
Wend
```

Answer (score 0):

you could consider a different approach:

- looping through rows in reverse order from last one to first one
- using `AutoFilter()` and `Specialcells()` methods of `Range` object to isolate blocks of contiguous not empty cells where to write totals formulas

like follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim area As Range

    With Range("B1", Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
        For iRow = .Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
            If .Cells(iRow, 1) <> .Cells(iRow + 1, 1) Then .Rows(iRow + 1).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
        Next
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 0 Then
            Set area = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
            For Each area In area.Areas
                With area.Offset(area.Rows.Count).Resize(1)
                    .Offset(, 5).Formula = "=SUM(" & Intersect(Range("E:G"), area.EntireRow).Address & ")"
                    .Offset(, 7).Formula = "=SUM(" & Intersect(Range("H:I"), area.EntireRow).Address & ")"
                    .Offset(, 8).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC7-RC9"
                    .Offset(, 9).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC10/RC7"
                End With
            Next
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```